# Printing values in * instead of numbers

Tags: c#, loops

Please I'm having an issue on how to generate a star rating. What i mean is that, after a user has inputed values for rating parameters and the program has calculated the total rate, how will the program produce the result in stars and not in figures. If the rating is 5 it should generate *****. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for

```
  int rating = 5;
  String starRating = new String('*', rating);
```

no (*visible* - xanatos comments) loops

Comment: *no loops* ... more exactly it should be *no visible loops*. The time/space complexity of this operation is still O(n)

Comment: @xanatos Very possibly, the loop could be unrolled.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop:

```
string result = new String('*', 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most succinct way would be to use the [`char, int` overload of the `string` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w(v=vs.110).aspx). For example:

```
int numberOfStars = 5;
string stringOfStars = new string('*', numberOfStars);
```

The naive way of course (most likely what the above does under the hood) would be to use a loop. For example we can output to the console directly and end with a single newline:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStars; ++i)
    Console.Write("*");
Console.WriteLine();
```